# Specifying schema on JSON via Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, schema

I would like to specify a schema when reading from a json but when trying to map a number to a Double it fails, I tried FloatType and IntType with no joy!

When inferring the schema customer id is set to String, and I would like to cast it as Double

so df1 is corrupted while df2 shows

Also FYI I need this to be generic as I would like to apply it to any json, I specified the below schema as an example of the issue I am facing

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{BinaryType, StringType, StructField, DoubleType,FloatType, StructType, LongType,DecimalType}
val testSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("customerid",DoubleType)))
val df1 = spark.read.schema(testSchema).json(sc.parallelize(Array("""{"customerid":"535137"}""")))
val df2 = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(Array("""{"customerid":"535137"}""")))
df1.show(1)
df2.show(1)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am sure I am missing something obvious but for the life of me I cant tell what it is!

Let me clarify, I am loading a file that is saved using sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD

So converting a RDD[JsonObject] to a dataframe while applying the schema to it

Answer (score 0):

The Json field since enclosed by double quotes is considered as a `String` .How about casting the column to Double?. this casting solution can be made generic if the details on what columns are expected to casted to Double is provided.

```
df1.select(df1("customerid").cast(DoubleType)).show()
+----------+
|customerid|
+----------+
|  535137.0|
+----------+
```

Comment: Hi @rogue-one sadly not sure how this can be done because I am loading the data from an HDFS-like storage, Google storage to be exact. So is there a better way than mapping through each row and removing the double quotes?